# How to check-in assets in a Rake Task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, github

I'm building a rails rake task to check-in assets and running into issues: errors:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

Here are the commands in the rake task:

```
def push_assets
  puts "===== Pushing assets to github..."

  system("git add public/assets")
  system("git commit -m 'production prepared assets' ")
  system("git push")

  puts "===== Push complete..."
end
```

Any ideas what is being done wrong in the method? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have already committed the changes. ( did you run this script once before?)

To redo the commit, you can do `git reset HEAD^`

To make your task idempotent, you can use `git status --porcelain` or `git diff --name-only` or something to see if there are changes to be checked-in in assets. If there are, only then proceed with the commit.

Comment: Where would I do git reset? I don't want to reset everything just the assets directoy? I would like to prevent an error if someone runs the rake task twice?

Comment: The last commit probably only did the addition of the assets directory and committed that. So `git reset HEAD^` would only do that. To make your task idempotent, you can use `git status --porcelain` or something to see if there are changes to be checked-in in assets.